# Tensorflow: 3D tensor and 2D matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

When passing a 3D tensor through a dense layer, I have seen implementations in the following way:

```
X = np.random.rand(5,4,3).astype(np.float32)
place = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
dense = tf.layers.dense(place, 10)
```

On the other hand, I have seen this as well:

```
X = np.random.rand(5,4,3).astype(np.float32)
place = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
place_reshape = tf.reshape(place, [tf.shape(place)[0] * tf.shape(place)[1], 3])
dense = tf.layers.dense(place_reshape, 10)
dense_reshape = tf.reshape(dense, [tf.shape(place)[0], tf.shape(place)[1], 10])
```

Although the two approaches should essentially be the same, I can't get the same result with the first and the second approach even though I am also setting both random seeds(I have omitted them from the code snippets for readability). Can someone point me in the right direction in case I am missing something?

Looking forward to you answers!

Comment: The first one won't work because the ranks must be equal to 2 in `matmul`. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want `matmul` to be broadcasted?

Comment: 1. It works, it doesn't raise an error.
2. The outputs from both code snippets should be the same (Tried the same thing in PyTorch and they are), so I am trying to figure out what makes them different.